# Permute strings with a learning curve, possibly neural network?

Tags: string, algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

## Intro

Need some directions or genuine advice on this issue by somebody more experienced.

Say I have a string of K words as an input for a search method which yields a result. The result can be marked as good(+1) or bad(-1). On the next "similar" search I'd like to use this good/bad score to alter the input string gently. In case this yields a better result I'd re-enforce this or avoid if not.

I use Jaccard's Index (Jaccard Similarity) for matching strings by "similarity". I also keep a record of all of the input/output patterns and feedback score on each.

Allowed morphs on the string involve: reordering word(s), removing word(s) (possibly adding words from the output pattern sample)

My professor suggested that a back-propagition neural network would be a good idea. I've worked with some simple feed forward neural networks and hopfield networks before, but before I take this journey I'd like to know if there might be some more simple techniques to tackle this?

## Example (Input:Output)

Say I have this I/O pattern saved:

What is the capital of France? : The capital of France is Paris.
(+1)

For the input
**What is the meaning of life?** a good morph would be **The meaning of life is**

My current algorithm works very well at finding answers to questions by scoring strings via similarity and context (not important how for the question) but just a slight re-arrangement of the words (or removal) would yield much better results. Verified this manually but I'd like the system to adapt and actually "learn" on its own.

Comment: If you want to design a system that rearranges NEW sequences of words, then a NN could work. If you just want to arrange the phrases you already have, then a meta-heuristic (like GA) would be better IMO

Comment: I have had GA on my mind but just to clarify what you mean by rearrange NEW phrases? Do you mean re arranging and adding words and not just reorder/removal?@Chris

Comment: If you know all sentences ahead of time, and that's all you want to do - then there's no machine learning required, just optimize your set of sentences. If you want to "learn" on the sentences you have and then have it work on *new* sentences, then you need ML.